# How can I use lookbehind in a C# Regex in order to remove line breaks?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text file with the repetitve structure as a header and a detail records such as

```
StopService::
697::12::test::20::a@yahoo.com::20 Main Rd::Alcatraz::CA::1200::Please send me Information to
A@gmail.com::0::::
```

I want to remove the line break between the header and the detail record so as to process them as a single record, as the detail record can contain line breaks as well I need to remove only the line breaks that follow directly the `::` sign.

I'm not a pro when using regular expressions so I searched and tried to use this approach but it doesn't work:

```
 string text = File.ReadAllText(path);
 Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<=(:))(?!\1):\n", String.Empty);
 File.WriteAllText(path, text);
```

I also tried this:

```
Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<=::)\n", String.Empty);
```

Any idea how I can use a regex look-behind in this case?
My output should look like this:

```
StopService::697::12::test::20::a@yahoo.com::20 Main Rd::Alcatraz::CA::1200::Please send me Information to
    A@gmail.com::0::::
```

Comment: What a regex. You capture a colon and then use a back reference to it inside a lookahead that makes sure the next character is not a colon, and then a colon. No wonder it does not work. Try `(?<=[^:]::)[\r\n]+` and replace with `string.Empty`.

Comment: Thank you, it didn't work either.

Comment: I believe nothing will work since we do not know from your description HOW that must work. Provide expected output for your given string. Unclear questions tend to receive unclear answers, thereis one already.

Comment: I added my desired result,I only need the line break between `StopService::` and the rest of the record to be removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Non-regex Way

Read a file line by line. Check the first line and if it is equal to `StopService::` do not add a newline (`Environment.Newline`) after it.

---

## Regex way

You can match the line break after the first `::` using a `(?<=^[^:]*::)` look-behind:

```
var str = "StopService::\r\n697::12::test::20::a@yahoo.com::20 Main Rd::Alcatraz::CA::1200::Please send me Information to\r\nA@gmail.com::0::::";
var rgx = new Regex(@"(?<=^[^:]*::)[\r\n]+");
Console.WriteLine(rgx.Replace(str, string.Empty));
```

Output:

```
StopService::697::12::test::20::a@yahoo.com::20 Main Rd::Alcatraz::CA::1200::Please send me Information to
A@gmail.com::0::::
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/JdwstV)

The look-behind (`(?<=...)`) matches:

- `^` - Start of string
- `[^:]*` - 0 or more characters other than `:`
- `::` - 2 colons

The `[\r\n]+` pattern makes sure we match all newline symbols, even if there is more than one.

Comment: Although more space is devoted to a regex solution, I'd use a non-regex one. Up to you to decide.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`Regex.Replace(yourtext, @"(?<=[::])[\r\n|\n|\r]", string.empty);`

You were on the right track with the lookbehind idea.  But you need to look for a newline and/or/both a carriage return...

Answer (score 1):

Here's my quick attempt. It may need some tweaks, as I just dummied up two records for input.

The approach is to define a Regex that identifies the header, line break, and detail (which may include line breaks). Then, just run a replace that puts the header back together with the detail, throwing out the header/detail line break.

The RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace option is used to allow whitespace in the expression for better readability.

```
var text = "StopService::" + Environment.NewLine;
text += "697::12::test::20::a@yahoo.com::20 Main Rd::Alcatraz::CA::1200::Please send me Information to" + Environment.NewLine;
text += "A@gmail.com::0::::"  + Environment.NewLine;
text += "StopService::" + Environment.NewLine;
text += "697::12::test::20::a@yahoo.com::20 Main Rd::Alcatraz::CA::1200::Please send me Information to" + Environment.NewLine;
text += "A@gmail.com::0::::"  + Environment.NewLine;

var options = RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace;
var matchRegex = new Regex("(?<header>\\w+?::) \\r\\n (?<detail>.+?::::)", options );
var replacement = "${header}${detail}";

var newText = matchRegex.Replace(text,replacement);
```

Produces:

```
StopService::697::12::test::20::a@yahoo.com::20 Main Rd::Alcatraz::CA::1200::Please send me Information to
A@gmail.com::0::::
StopService::697::12::test::20::a@yahoo.com::20 Main Rd::Alcatraz::CA::1200::Please send me Information to
A@gmail.com::0::::
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

```
yourtext.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," ");
```

I haven't tested C# one. It should work something like below.

C#:

```
Regex.Replace(yourtext, @"/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm", " ");
```

Comment: The "m" stands for multi-line matching.